# RBF transformation on a Normally Distributed Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation, covariance

I have a random vector $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m,\Sigma})$ which is transformed by a Gaussian Radial Basis Function into the random variable $\mathbf{Y} = K(\mathbf X)$ where $K = \exp(-\lambda||\mathbf X||^2)$ is there an analytic expression for the mean and variance of this new variable?